# How come every compact connected surface admits a presentation in which all vertices are identified with a single point?

Tags: algebraic-topology, surfaces

I've been stuck for a while now on this step of the classification theorem proof in *Introduction to Topological Manifolds* by John Lee:

> STEP 4: M admits a presentation in which all vertices are identified to a single
> point.

Where M is a connected compact surface.

I don't understand how could this be true. Take a (bounded) cylinder for example. It has the following presentation: $aba^{-1}c$. I don't see how all vertices could be mapped to the same point, that could only happen if we turn it into a torus (i.e. identify b and c together). The key step in the above proof seems to be that he's assuming that for every edge $b$ there is another edge $b$ or $b^{-1}$ with which it is identified; but again: that's not true in the case of the cylinder, not all edges are identified. The same problem happens if we consider the presentation of a mobius band for example and other surfaces as well. I've rechecked the definitions several times to see if I was missing something basic but I'm not able to see where I went wrong so I would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Are you sure the author is not talking about *closed* (i.e. without boundary) surfaces? Because surfaces with boundary in general cannot be represented in such a way.

Comment: I just skimmed through the chapter and didn't see him mention it explicitly although after the classification theorem he states and I quote "This classification theorem leads easily to a characterization of compact 2-manifolds with boundary (see Problem 6-5)". So I guess he is indeed talking about manifolds without boundary even though I didn't see him mention it. I think this resolves the issue so thank you.